# Storing state of child components with clean code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Short Explanation**
I just want to get the data from the textboxes and send them to the server. In jquery I would just list out all my textboxes and get the value and form the json and send it to the server

Please see example code
https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-euclid-3bl7tc

```
const EMPTY_VALUE = "";
const App = () => {
  const [valueFirstName, setValueFirstName] = React.useState(EMPTY_VALUE);
  const [valueMiddleName, setValueMiddleName] = React.useState(EMPTY_VALUE);
  const [valueLastName, setValueLastName] = React.useState(EMPTY_VALUE);

  return (
    <div>
      First Name:
      <Work365TextBox value={valueFirstName} setValue={setValueFirstName} />
      <div>{valueFirstName}</div>
      Middle Name:
      <Work365TextBox value={valueMiddleName} setValue={setValueMiddleName} />
      <div>{valueMiddleName}</div>
      Last Name:
      <Work365TextBox value={valueLastName} setValue={setValueLastName} />
      <div>{valueLastName}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Problem**

The current code has a label for first name, middle name, and last name and components to contain the textboxes and then the state of the component is stored in the parent.Then the parent takes the state and displays it below the textbox. So the solution works great. But the code is messy

**Question**
If I have a form that asks for 20 values what is a cleaner way to handle this ? I have tried to do this with by defining a object as json and calling a method when the value in each textbox changes but then I need to have a method for each textbox I have on the screen and it doesn't seem very clean. How would you solve this problem in a clean way ? Preferably I want to be able to have 50 textbox components but just call one method to update state.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to use a state management library (which can overcomplicate things like this) or to use libraries such as [`react-hook-form`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-form). Or perhaps you're asking about extracting the Label/div with the `<Work365TextBox>` into a separate component.

Comment: am I going about this the correct way ? or is there a totally different solution to do the same task ?

Comment: I just want to get the data from the textboxes and send them to the server. In jquery I would just list out all my textboxes and get the value and form the json and send it to the server

Comment: For forms, libraries like formik should be able to handle most use cases https://formik.org/docs/examples/basic

Comment: What do you mean `have 50 textbox components but just call one method to update state` ? Update what state? If I'm understanding the question correctly you should consider storing an array in your state.

Comment: ok an array sure. But when each textbox updates there needs to be a different method for each place in the array ? if not how would you do it with one method ?

Answer (score 0):

the object solution you mentioned is a great way.
one thing to add is that you can pass a `name` prop to your input and then in the onChange method you can access it via `event.target.name`
that way you can dynamically update your object
something like this

```
  const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
  };
```

another solution is to define it with useReducer but that will need a extra code.

Comment: can you show me what that would look like on the component declaration side ? 
 <Work365TextBox value={valueFirstName} setValue={setValueFirstName} Name='FirstName' /> ?

Comment: yes exactly .
just make sure that Work365TextBox component should get name as a prop and also passed that prop to the input component

Comment: how do I get the Name='Firstname' to be put on the event ?

Comment: it's the default behavior of <input /> component you don't need to do anything.
i created a codesandbox so you can better understand 
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-feynman-f63pxz?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I would just use an array like that:

```
// one item for each textbox
const textboxes = [
  {
    // human-readable label
    label: "First name",
    // unique key for data access
    key: "firstName"
  },
  {
    label: "Middle name",
    key: "middleName"
  },
  {
    label: "Last name",
    key: "lastName"
  }
];
```

A state like this:

```
const [values, setValues] = React.useState(
  // converts array to record-like object
  Object.fromEntries(textboxes.map((box) => [box.key, ""]))
);

const handleChange = (key, value) => {
  setValues((values) => ({ ...values, [key]: value }));
};
```

And render it like this:

```
<div>
  {textboxes.map((box) => (
    <>
      {box.label}:
      <Work365TextBox
        value={values[box.key]}
        setValue={(value) => handleChange(box.key, value)}
      />
      <div>{values[box.key]}</div>
    </>
  ))}
</div>
```

[Full example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-turing-jh2xor?file=/app/main.jsx:556-837)

Comment: kinda hard to control layout of the controls this way no ?

Comment: Yes, that's why `react-hook-form` or other libraries are usually a better choice